# Error in shap - AttributeError: module 'shap' has no attribute 'TreeExplainer'

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

when I'm using:

```
gb_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer
```

I get this error:

```
 AttributeError: module 'shap' has no attribute 'TreeExplainer'
```

The full code:

```
    def create_shap_tree_explainer(self):

        self.gb_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(self.gb_model)
        self.shap_values_X_test =   self.gb_explainer.shap_values(self.X_test)
        self.shap_values_X_train =  self.gb_explainer.shap_values(self.X_train)
```

The gradient boosting classifier model is:

```
  gbc_model = Create_Gradient_Boosting_Classifier(X_train, y_train, ps)
```

Comment: Please full [reprex] leading to your error, including `shap` version

Answer (score 1):

This is a filename conflict issue. The error message shows that the custom module (.py file) that contains your script has the same name as the built-in 'shap' module. The program attempts to access the TreeExpainer attribute from your custom 'shap' module, resulting in an error because your module has no such attribute. One way to resolve this is to give your custom module a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Which SHAP do you use?
Please check it.

```
print(shap.__version__)
```

Also, did you install SHAP via `pip` or `conda`? Where your python access when you run the script? I think, after such checks you will get the answer what is going on.